# requirement failed: Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This is my code：

```
spark = get_spark_session(app_name="test")
df = spark.sql(sql)
result_value = df.collect()[0][0]
print(result_value)
...
```

However, when I was running, I made the following mistakes. Although I saw many similar problems, I still don't know how to deal with them. I hope someone can help me, thank you.

```py
response:<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 50, in <module>
    result_value = df.collect()[0][0]
  File "/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 535, in collect
    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o425.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 909 in stage 32.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 909.3 in stage 32.0 (TID 8476, localhost, executor 5): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.set(Decimal.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$.apply(Decimal.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal.apply(Decimal.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getDecimal(UnsafeRow.java:409)
```

I searched a few questions, but still couldn't find the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss
```

I found the answer to this question. spark has a parameter that affects the accuracy of the data.